# What service click-system-hooks.service in Ubuntu

Tags: startup, services

Trying to speed up my system, I have Ubuntu 16.10, analyze the system, checked what services slow down, disconnected `apt-daily.service` as automatic check for new updates I don't need.

Please explain what service is responsible for the `click-system-hooks.servic`e and whether it can be deactivated.

```
$ systemd-analyze blame
26.630s apt-daily.service
17.067s click-system-hooks.service
```

Sorry for my bad English, I'm from Ukraine, looking at the Russian forums and not found an answer for what you use - `click-system-hooks.service` and is it possible to disable it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wondered also what this may be on my Ubuntu installation, so I had a look at the service file `/lib/systemd/system/click-system-hooks.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run Click system-level hooks
Documentation=man:click(1)

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/click hook run-system
Restart=no

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

So, it is responsible for invoking `/usr/bin/click hook run-system`. According to its [man-page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/yakkety/en/man1/click.1.html), click is a

> package management tool for Ubuntu Touch

and the parameters `hook run-system` mean

```
Run all system-level hooks for all installed Click packages. This is useful when starting up from images with preinstalled packages which may not have had their system-level hooks run properly when building the image.
```

Concluding, if you don't run Ubuntu Touch, you may disable the service via `sudo systemctl disable click-system-hooks.service` or remove click completely from your system.

For me, I suspect, it came with the package `unity8-desktop-session` which indirectly depends on click and must not be installed without.