# Slow Ubuntu 17.04 boot with home not encrypted

Tags: boot, 17.04

it takes Ubuntu 1 minute and about 18 seconds to get to the login screen on my dell inspiron 5110. Then about 30 seconds until the desktop is loaded. My home is not encrypted. So the solution suggested
[in this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/905031/ubuntu-desktop-17-04-64-bit-with-encrypted-home-slow-boot) doesn't apply.

The output of systemd-analyze blame is

```
27.732s click-system-hooks.service
     18.504s dev-sda5.device
     17.309s snapd.service
     15.811s winbind.service
     14.011s apparmor.service
     12.583s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      9.507s grub-common.service
      8.834s accounts-daemon.service
      8.538s gpu-manager.service
      7.846s teamviewerd.service
      6.096s NetworkManager.service
      5.523s upower.service
      4.510s networking.service
      4.103s smbd.service
      3.626s thermald.service
      3.596s dns-clean.service
      3.592s binfmt-support.service
      3.581s runhwactivator.service
      3.513s apport.service
      3.505s apache-htcacheclean.service
      3.499s rsyslog.service
      3.475s pppd-dns.service
      3.386s wpa_supplicant.service
      2.727s systemd-logind.service
      2.538s systemd-rfkill.service
      2.530s plymouth-start.service
      2.499s avahi-daemon.service
      2.257s colord.service
      2.183s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
      2.115s user@1000.service
      1.908s lightdm.service
      1.898s polkit.service
      1.830s keyboard-setup.service
      1.763s console-setup.service
      1.694s dev-loop4.device
      1.665s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      1.576s dev-loop3.device
      1.549s systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
      1.379s systemd-update-utmp.service
      1.357s dev-loop0.device
      1.264s systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video1.service
      1.189s systemd-modules-load.service
      1.164s systemd-resolved.service
      1.129s systemd-udev-trigger.service
      1.129s sys-kernel-debug.mount
       970ms systemd-udevd.service
       932ms snap-atom-30.mount
       920ms systemd-journal-flush.service
       883ms udisks2.service
       861ms systemd-user-sessions.service
       759ms dev-hugepages.mount
       755ms systemd-backlight@leds:dell::kbd_backlight.service
       754ms dev-mqueue.mount
       626ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
       618ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       522ms resolvconf.service
       493ms ufw.service
       493ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       473ms dev-loop1.device
       468ms snap-core-3017.mount
       461ms systemd-journald.service
       430ms dev-loop2.device
       425ms snap-core-2844.mount
       421ms systemd-sysctl.service
       388ms systemd-random-seed.service
       384ms snap-atom-20.mount
       376ms alsa-restore.service
       317ms rc-local.service
       308ms snap-core-2898.mount
       299ms setvtrgb.service
       250ms snap-atom-36.mount
       205ms dev-loop5.device
       197ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
       113ms systemd-remount-fs.service
        57ms plymouth-read-write.service
        48ms rtkit-daemon.service
        45ms snapd.autoimport.service
        31ms snapd.socket
        13ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         6ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
         5ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
```

The output of /etc/fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=ddee4415-d44a-41bd-b1b7-978f699666ff /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=d4df51a1-e991-47ea-920b-02502d4f7226
```

The output of df -h

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           588M   17M  571M   3% /run
/dev/sda5       338G  190G  132G  60% /
tmpfs           2.9G   23M  2.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop3       84M   84M     0 100% /snap/core/3017
/dev/loop5       82M   82M     0 100% /snap/core/2898
/dev/loop1      172M  172M     0 100% /snap/atom/30
/dev/loop2      173M  173M     0 100% /snap/atom/36
/dev/loop4      172M  172M     0 100% /snap/atom/20
/dev/loop0       82M   82M     0 100% /snap/core/2844
tmpfs           588M  112K  588M   1% /run/user/1000
```

systemd-analyze

```
Startup finished in 12.490s (kernel) + 1min 27.460s (userspace) = 1min 39.951s
```

Comment: This seems related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/843221/what-service-click-system-hooks-service-in-ubuntu. There are quite a few extras, and they take time to load. Consider disabling stuff you don't need.

Comment: I have disable winbind and click-system-hooks. But now the dev-sda5.device takes more than a minute alone.

Comment: How full is sda5 - `df -h`? Also, what's the output of `systemd-analyze time`?

Comment: Well, /dev/sda5 is not full, so next, I'd try changing the I/O scheduler, as outlined here https://askubuntu.com/questions/78682/how-do-i-change-to-the-noop-scheduler/473992. From what I've see, cfq is better for HDDs, while deadline has better performance for SSDs. It may reduce boot time by a few seconds, but temper your expectations, an old laptop won't get blazingly fast.

Comment: using /proc/swaps, I found that I have no swap file. Could this have something to do with the problem? Also, this problem didn't exist with previous versions of Ubuntu I was running on this particular laptop.

Comment: ...and how much RAM is there? You could try to create a swap file, just to check if it helps.

Comment: I have 6 GB of RAM. I have already tried to create a swap file using commands available in the answer to [this question] [1]. But running /proc/swaps after reboot returns nothing. [1] https://askubuntu.com/questions/904628/default-17-04-swap-file-location

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67049/discussion-between-mohamed-ahmed-and-mikewhatever).